# Populating data onto Google Map with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a rails app that uses Google Maps API to find pick up games in your area. You can create games and set the place you wanna play at using the Places library (I have that bit down). However, now I'm trying to make it so that when you click a button, it takes those locations people have created and populates them on the map.

I have a games model with the an address column, and i'm trying to take that address information and have it pop up on the map when a user presses the button.

Does anyone have tips on how I can do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with the help of two gems:

```
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

Although you can certainly plot addresses, I like to convert those to long and lat coordinates with an 'after_save' method (You would have to add two columns to your Game model).

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_save :cache_coordinates

  def cache_coordinates
    loc = Geocoder.coordinates(address)
    return if loc.nil?
    update_column(:latitude,  loc[0])
    update_column(:longitude, loc[1])
  end
end
```

Make sure to follow the instructions outlined here to get Gmaps working:
[Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)

Your Maps controller can look something like this (Don't forget to add to routes...)

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @geolocations = Game.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@geolocations) do |geolocation, marker|
      marker.lat geolocation.latitude
      marker.lng geolocation.longitude
    end
  end
end
```

And a simple view would be something like this:

```
// use your API key here...
<%= javascript_include_tag "//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.23&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry&key=YOURKEY" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "//cdn.rawgit.com/mahnunchik/markerclustererplus/master/dist/markerclusterer.min.js" %>
<script>
    var mapStyle = [];
    var mapOptions = {};
    var handler = Gmaps.build('Google',
            {markers:
            {clusterer: {
                gridSize: 20,
                maxZoom: 13
            }}});
    handler.buildMap({
        internal: {id: 'multi_markers'},
        provider: {
            scrollwheel: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

    }, function(){
        var markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
        // some options you may or may not want to use
        handler.map.centerOn([40.397, -95.644]);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();
        handler.getMap().setZoom(4)
    });
</script>
```